# How to use JWT Auth0 token for Cloud Run Service to Service communication if the Metaserver Token is overriding the Auth0 Token

Tags: jwt, google-cloud-run

#### Prerequisites

I have two Cloud Run services a `frontend` and a `backend`. The frontend is written in Vue.js/Nuxt.js and is using a Node backend therefore. The backend is written in Kotlin with Spring Boot.

#### Problem

To have an authenticated internal communication between the frontend and the backend I need to use a token thttps://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#javahat is fetched from the google metaserver. This is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#java

I did set it all up and it works.

For my second layer of security I integrated the Auth0 authentication provider both in my frontend and my backend. In my frontend a user can log in. The frontend is calling the backend API. Since only authorized users should be able to call the backend I integrated Spring Security to secure the backend API endpoints.

Now the backend verifies if the token of the caller's request are valid before allowing it to pass on to the API logic.

However this theory does not work. And that simply is because I delegate the API calls through the Node backend proxy. The proxy logic however is already applying a token to the request to the backend; it is the google metaserver token. So let me illustrate that:

`Client (Browser) -> API Request with Auth0 Token -> Frontend Backend Proxy -> Overriding Auth0 Token with Google Metaserver Token -> Calling Backend API`

Since the backend is receiving the metaserver token instead of the Auth0 Token it can never successfully authorize the API call.

#### Question

Due the fact that I was not able to find any articles about this problem I wonder if it's simply because I am doing it basically wrong.

What do I need to do to have a valid Cloud Run Service to Service communication (guaranteed by the metaserver token) but at the same time have a secured backend API with Auth0 authorization?

I see two workarounds to make this happen:

- Authorize the API call in the Node backend proxy logic
- Make the backend service public available thus the metaserver token is unnecessary

I don't like any of the above - especially the latter one. I would really like to have it working with my current setup but I have no idea how. There is no such thing like multiple authorization token, right?

Comment: just adding appreciation for the question as its the exact issue we were facing

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured out a third way to have a de-facto internal service to service communication.

To omit the meta-server token authentication but still restrict access from the internet I did the following for my `backend` cloud run service:

[image]

This makes the service available from the internet **however** the ingress is preventing any outsider from accessing the service. The service is available without IAM but **only** for internal traffic.

So my `frontend` is calling the `backend` API now via the Node backend proxy. Even though the `frontend` node-backend and the `backend` service are both somewhat "in the cloud" they do not share the same "internal network". In fact the `frontend` node-backend requests would be redirected via egress to the internet and call the `backend` service just like any other internet-user would do.

To make it work "like it is coming from internal" you have to do something similar like VPN but it's called VPC (Virtual Private Cloud). And luckily that is very simple. Just create a VPC Connector in GCP.

**BUT** be aware to create a so called **Serverless VPC Access** (Connector). Explained here: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/serverless-vpc-access

After the Serverless VPC Access has been created you can select it in your Cloud Run Service "Connection" settings. For the `backend` service it can be simply selected. For the `frontend` service however it is important to select the second option:

[image]

At least that is important in my case since I am calling the `backend` service by it's assigned service URL instead of a private IP.

---

After all that is done my JWT token from the `frontend` is successfully delivered to the `backend` API without being overwritten by a MetaServer token.

Comment: Its a good solution - many thanks!   Lets hope there are more options such as whitelisting or SA based ingress options to CR soon